# Access ng-repeat repeating data inside appended html

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-repeat

I am appending some HTML into a model item when that item is clicked using custom directive.

My code:

```
<div appenddata>
    <div ng-repeat="model in models">
        <label ng-bind="model.name"></label>
    </div>
<div>

directive('appenddata', function($compile) {
   // click handlers
   $(element).after("<p ng-bind='model.name'></p>);
   $compile(html)(scope);
});
```

Is it possible to access model item data in this appended html?

Comment: you should really let the controller drive your view. click event should modify the data in your controller and the view should react to the data change accordingly,it will make your life easier trust me. There are only very rare use cases for using  $compile,$eval and stuff like that.

Comment: I have around 250 items. When I load all the items, the app is very slow in device. So I thought of trying out this way so as to populate DOM only when clicked

Comment: See http://binarymuse.github.io/ngInfiniteScroll/ and how it works, it may give you some idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like the comments have mentioned, you really shouldn't be injecting data into the DOM yourself. If you need to change how much data is shown in the DOM, use a filter on your ng-repeat.

Also, 250 items in an ng-repeat shouldn't be enough to slow down a page unless there's some pretty heavy processing occurring on each item. I would suggest using something like [Angular Batarang](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/angularjs-batarang/ighdmehidhipcmcojjgiloacoafjmpfk?hl=en) to profile your application to see what's actually causing it to be slow.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible, I recently asked something simular:

[Create div with angular variable as attribute value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23547310/create-div-with-angular-variable-as-attribute-value)

This code was suggested:

```
angular.element($("#canvas")).injector().invoke(function($compile) {
  var scope = angular.element($("#canvas")).scope();
  var compiledImg = $compile('<img id="editImage" ng-src={{ImageToEdit}}>')(scope);
  $("#canvas").replaceWith(compiledImg);
});
```